# How to download & install “heidisql” on linux?

Tags: software-installation, system-installation

First time I am starting working on "heidisql". I want to download & install "heidisql" on Linux Mint. May anybody please provide me the link to download "heidisql" for Linux version & how to install? Actually after googling I am not getting proper result.

Comment: "HeidiSQL runs fine on Windows (XP, Vista, 7, 8) and - with Wine - on any Linux and newer MacOS X versions." - from the top link for heidisql on Google. What do you make of that? What have you attempted so far to get it running under Wine?

Comment: i already install "HeidiSQL_8.3.0.4694_Setup.exe" but how to download "Wine"... whenever i clicked on the Wine link it redirect to download.php page... & how to setup..??

Comment: Did you search? "linux mint install wine" in your favorite search engine should bring lots of stuff.

Comment: when i try to run cmd on terminal "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa", got this error "Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A good **alternative** to Heidi that runs on Linux without wine is dbeaver. It's a Java app and the user interface will be familiar for users of HeidiSQL.

https://dbeaver.io/

#### Installation instructions

How to install DBeaver 2.3.6 on **32 bit** Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Elementary OS, Debian, Crunchbang and KWheezy systems:

```
$ wget -c https://dbeaver.io/files/dbeaver-ce_latest_i386.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i dbeaver-ce_latest_i386.deb
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

How to install DBeaver 2.3.6 on **64 bit** Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Elementary OS, Debian, Crunchbang and KWheezy systems:

```
$ wget -c https://dbeaver.io/files/dbeaver-ce_latest_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i dbeaver-ce_latest_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

[Source](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-dbeaver-2-3-6-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-pear-os-elementary-os-debian-crunchbang-and-kwheezy/)

Comment: it hangs.Onl killing the app helps, then it works for some time and hard kill is neded again to work

Answer (score 4):

HeidiSQL runs nicely on Linux using [`wine` (Wine Is Not an Emulator)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)).

**To Install:**

1. If not already installed, install **wine** with: `sudo apt-get install wine`
2. Install **[HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/)** with: `wine HeidiSQL_some-version-#_Setup.exe`

Now in the menu category named **wine** you'll find your new **HeidiSQL** launcher.

---

**To upgrade:**  Reinstall HeidiSQL with the new *.exe file.

---

Extra tips:

Have been using HeidiSQL for about a year now.  I use HeidiSQL to edit my MariaDB (mySQL) database design, and then use LibreOffice as the MariaDB front end.  It works pretty good.

I keep my database programs organized in the menu in a new custom folder named **Database**.

In HeidiSQL save table edits before moving to something else and you should be all good.  At one time if you moved the focus to a new thing without saving first she would crash. I'm guessing it's been fixed by now.  The developer seems pretty smart and keeps the thing running nicely.

*My 2nd divorce was from a woman named Heidi.  She Dropped me.. and I'm better off for it.*

Answer (score 3):

Heidisql is a Windows application. This can run in Linux using the wine software.

First install wine (sudo apt-get install wine) and then you should be able to run the heidisql installer by just double clicking the icon.

Comment: heidisql is the best sql program I have encountered.  Even on wine it beats dbeaver, except for occasional crashes when I alter table columns.

Answer (score 2):

Another good alternative for Ubuntu is `MySQL Workbench`

To install it :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```